# Is there a standard way to indicate that a function returns a new pointer?

Tags: c++, coding-standards

Sometimes I want to delegate the construction of objects that a class owns to a separate function. Something like

```
Vertex* new_vertex(const Options& options) {
  // do stuff...
  return new Vertex(...);
}
```

where the function is only intended to be used to within a class that owns the `Vertex`. Clearly this function can cause some memory-leaking confusion, so I want to make it as clear as possible. Is there a naming convention for such functions?

Comment: Yes.  `// TODO: Fix allocation of raw pointer.`

Comment: @StevenBurnap I wouldn't use the word "fix" unless the thing doesn't work.

Comment: Just a remark on the concern of "confusion". It is equally important that the caller takes proper care of the returned object. Smart pointers can make this effortless (by making memory management a mechanical habit rather than a continuous exertion of mental effort), but if the caller doesn't have any clear policy or coding standard or notion of hierarchical "object ownership", eventually it will still run into trouble. In some cases, junior programmers might even try to circumvent the `unique_ptr` by calling its `release()` function, and use the raw pointers like the old ways.

Comment: What I take away from these comments (and the answer so far) is that one should never, _ever_ return a raw pointer from a function that creates the object. Is this a rule even if the function is called in the constructor and _immediately_ passes the pointer to the object that (privately) owns it?

Comment: if you'd tagged your question C rather than C++ you might get answers in keeping with your original intent. Returning a smart pointer is the right way in C++, in C, there's no convention for naming except to write documentation, eg strdup.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Why not simply `// FIXME: Allocation of raw pointer`?

Comment: Your function makes it pretty clear to me.  The return type isn't by value or a reference - either of which would make trying to clear up the memory a non-instinctive syntactic wrangle.  The function is called `new_vertex` so I know the object is newly minted.  You could call it `Create_new_vertex` to be extra clear.  As for the idea that you shouldn't manage heap memory without smart pointers, never seen the truth in that - in fact if you can't manage heap memory *without* them, you've got no business managing heap memory *with* them either!

Comment: Sorry for the snark, but you really should just not allocate pointers without having some method that ensures that they will be deallocated that doesn't rely on the coder remembering.

Answer (score 21):

Return a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Vertex> new_vertex(const Options& options) {
  // do stuff...
  return std::make_unique<Vertex>(...);
}
```

There can only ever be one `unique_ptr` pointing to a given object (unless you abuse it by casting to a `Vertex*` and back, anyway). You can't ever copy a `unique_ptr`, only move it. When a `unique_ptr` is destroyed (and hasn't been moved out of) it even `delete`s the object for you.

`make_unique` creates a new `Vertex` and wraps it in a `unique_ptr`; the arguments you pass to `make_unique` are the arguments it passes to the constructor.

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't _really_ answer my question. I know about smart pointers, I just wanted to know if there's a naming convention for functions that return raw pointers that the user has to take care of. I guess the answer is "no, there isn't, because you should never do that"?

Comment: @Shep If you want to indicate to the person calling your function that it creates a new object, `unique_ptr` does that. If it has to be a name for some reason, then I guess it doesn't, but why does it have to be a name?

Comment: @Shep Names are intangible things and everyone is free to ignore them completely. Types on the other hand are enforced by the compiler, which means it requires significant effort to break stuff. Never send a name to do a type's job.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is also convertible to `shared_ptr` (though not vice versa) so a function returning a `unique_ptr` can still have the result moved to a `shared_ptr` if shared ownership is required.

Comment: @Shep there's no harm returning a raw pointer *in this case*.  This case being that you've created an object that it is up to the caller to manage the lifetime of. The caller can always drop it straight into a smart pointer if they think they need to.

Comment: @immibis: Why fo you override the template-argument-deduction of `std::make_unique`? That's unneccessarily verbose and error-prone...

Comment: If the one who calls `new_vertex` totally cannot live with a `std::unique_ptr`, they can always get back the raw pointer by calling its `release` member function. But the function's interface will be safe and explicit. I bet you won't be able to measure the performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard way to indicate that a function returns a new pointer?

No, there is no "standard way" (but there is an API design policy currently considered "best practice").

Because of this ambiguity ("what does a function returning a pointer want me to do with it?"), it is currently considered best practice to impose the lifetime and ownership policy, through the return type:

```
<vertex pointer type> new_vertex(const Options& options);
```

`<vertex pointer type>` can be `std::unique_ptr` ("new_vertex doesn't own the pointer"), or `std::shared_ptr` ("client code doesn't own the pointer"), or something else, that has clearly defined ownership semantics (for example, `Vertex const * const` would indicate to client code "read the address and values, but change neither/don't delete the pointer").

Generally, you should not return a raw pointer (but in some cases, "practicality beats purity").

**TLDR**: there is a best practice (**yes**), but not a standard way (in the language).

**Edit**:

> where the function is only intended to be used to within a class that owns the Vertex

If the class owns the Vertex, I would write it like this:

```
class SomeClass // owns the vertex
{
    void do_stuff() // uses the vertex internally
    {
        init_vertex(); // see below
        assert(vertex.get());
        // use vertex as needed
    }
private:
    // "class owns the Vertex"
    std::unique_ptr<Vertex> vertex;

    // sets the internal vertex
    // function doesn't return a pointer of any kind
    void init_vertex(const Options& options); // or "reset_", "refresh_", 
                                              // or "make_" vertex,
                                              // if the pointer can change
                                              // throughout the lifetime
                                              // of a SomeClass instance
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there are dozens of "standards" about this**

[image: XKCD]

The answer recommending `unique_ptr` is probably the best answer, but if you're looking at raw pointers, everyone's developed their own standard.

Generally speaking functions named `create_____` or `new______` or `alloc_____` tend to imply a new object.

**However**

Consider that you're mixing behaviors.  You don't actually care whether this is a new instance of an object or not.  **What you care about is whether the caller is responsible for destroying the object or not.**  There are many APIs which hand over the responsibility for an existing object, and those functions will need a matching naming scheme. Perhaps `give______`.

**If you're willing to step a little away from C++...**
If you're willing to consider Objective-C to be similar enough to C++ to be a source for an answer, there's actually a real answer in that language.  Objective-C manages the lifespan of objects using reference counts.  They needed a way to describe whether you were being given responsibility for an object, or merely a reference to an existing object.  If you get the answer wrong, you get the ref-counts wrong and lose objects.  Accordingly they made a rule: every object you are returned is owned by someone else (so you must increment and decrement the ref count yourself), except for creation calls which pass an already incremented pointer to you (you only have to decrement).  These calls were identified by the method name.  Methods starting with `alloc` `new` `copy` or `mutableCopy` always returned a new object.  So there, the standard was enforced by the language.